# modal does not display with side navbar overlap

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog, modalviewcontroller

> I am at my wits end trying to figure out how to make the sign in modal
>   mobile responsive and continue to show display when the screen is down
>   to 320x568.

Here is the modal html

```html
<body>
  <div class="navbar-fixed">
    <nav style="background-color: white;">
      <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <!-- Logo goes here -->
        <a [pphref="index.html" class="brand-logo right">
          <img class="responsive-img" src="../assets/images/HG3.png">
        </a>
        <!-- Collapsable menu is here -->
        <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse">
          <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
        </a>
        <ul class="left hide-on-med-and-down">
          <li class="active">
            <a href="index.html">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="contact.html#message">Contact Us</a>
          </li>

          <li>
            <a href="account.html">Favorites</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <!-- Modal Trigger, the 'href' points to the Modal Structure -->
            <a class="waves-effect waves-light loginbtn btn modal-trigger" data-toggle="modal" href="#login-modal" id="signInBtn">Sign In</a>
            <a class="waves-effect waves-light loginbtn btn modal-trigger" data-toggle="modal" href="#login-modal" id="signOutBtn">Sign Out</a>
            <!-- Modal Structure -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="login-modal" tabindex="-1" data-toggle="modal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
              <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header" align="center">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </button>
                  </div>
```

Here is CSS. Media queries are set at min-width. I'm not sure if I need to change the z-index and change things around that way.

```css
nav ul a,
nav .brand-logo {
  color: #444;
}

p {
  line-height: 2rem;
}


/* This css is for the .main class */

#main {
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch
}

.main-container {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: left .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: left .2s ease-in-out
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1440px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 20px
}

@media screen and (min-width:840px) {
  .container {
    padding: 0 40px
  }
}

.hero {
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url("../images/greenjuice.jpg");
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
  -webkit-transition: left .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: left .2s ease-in-out
}

.hero .container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column
}

.hero h1 {
  width: 100%;
  text-shadow: -2px 2px 10px rgba(55, 55, 55, 0.25)
}

#hero {
  position: fixed;
  top: 65px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1
}

#after-hero {
  margin-top: 100vh
}

.wf-active #hero .tag {
  -webkit-animation: opacity 1s ease;
  animation: opacity 1s ease;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards
}

.wf-active #hero h1 {
  -webkit-animation: opacity 2s ease .25s;
  animation: opacity 2s ease .25s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards
}

.hero--generic {
  background-image: url("../images/greenjuice.jpg");
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 400px
}

.hero--generic h1 {
  font-size: 48px
}

@media screen and (min-width:840px) {
  .hero--generic h1 {
    font-size: 700px
  }
}

.hero--index {
  background-image: url("../images/greenjuice.jpg")
}

.hero--index h1 {
  margin-bottom: .6em
}

.hero--index h1 {
  color: rgb(17, 22, 31)
}

.hero--index h3 {
  font-size: 48px;
  color: whitesmoke;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  text-shadow: -2px 2px 10px rgba(55, 55, 55, 0.25);
  line-height: 1.2em
}

.responsive-img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%
}

@media screen and (min-width:0) and (max-width:479px) {
  .hero--index h3 {
    display: none
  }
}

.hero--index .tag {
  color: #717f81
}


/* Css for .panel  */

.panel {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 15;
}

@media screen and (min-width:840px) {
  .panel--solutions {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between
  }
}

.solution {
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #656565
}

@media screen and (min-width:840px) {
  .solution {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    width: 50%;
    height: auto
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width:840px) {
  .solution:before {
    float: left;
    padding-top: 100%;
    content: ""
  }
}

.solution__container {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.801);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  /* padding:350px 200px; */
  width: 100%;
  margin: 200px 0px;
  /* margin-bottom: auto; */
  -webkit-transition: background-color .5s ease;
  transition: background-color .5s ease
}

@media screen and (min-width:1200px) {
  .solution__container {
    padding: 100px 80px
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width:1600px) {
  .solution__container {
    padding: 100px
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width:840px) {
  .solution__container:hover,
  .solution__container:focus {
    background-color: transparent
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width:840px) {
  .solution__container:hover .solution__inner,
  .solution__container:focus .solution__inner {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.904);
    border-color: transparent
  }
}

.solution__container p {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center
}

.solution__inner {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .6s ease;
  transition: all .6s ease
}

@media screen and (min-width:840px) {
  .solution__inner {
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    /* justify-content:center; */
    padding: 40px;
    border: 2px dashed #188138
  }
}

.solution__inner * {
  text-align: center
}

.solution__header {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #188138
}

@media screen and (min-width:840px) {
  .solution__header {
    font-size: 40px
  }
}

.solution__body {
  margin: 20px auto 30px;
  font-size: 16px
}

@media screen and (min-width:840px) {
  .solution__body {
    font-size: 18px
  }
}

.solution--ordering {
  background-image: url()
}

.solution--category {
  background-image: url()
}

.solution__icon {
  margin-bottom: 30px
}


/* End of main container css */


/* Start of footer css */

footer {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 16;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden
}

.panel--learn-more {
  background-color: #05180ae1;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .3s ease;
  transition: background-color .3s ease
}

@media screen and (min-width:840px) {
  .panel--learn-more {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 158px
  }
}

.panel--learn-more:hover,
.panel--learn-more:focus {
  background-color: #082505
}

.learn-more__header {
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 40px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: none
}

@media screen and (min-width:840px) {
  .learn-more__header {
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 35px
  }
}

.learn-more__link {
  font-style: italic;
  text-decoration: none
}

@media screen and (min-width:0) and (max-width:839px) {
  .learn-more__link {
    display: block
  }
  .solution__container {
    padding: 0px;
  }
}

.learn-more__link:hover,
.learn-more__link:focus {
  text-decoration: none
}

.footer__bottom {
  background-color: #233c23;
  overflow: hidden
}

.footer__bottom .container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 190px
}

@media screen and (min-width:840px) {
  .footer__bottom .container {
    height: 100px;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row
  }
}

.footer__navigation {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center
}

@media screen and (min-width:840px) {
  .footer__navigation {
    margin: 0 30px
  }
}

.footer__navigation a {
  color: #fff
}

.footer__navigation a:hover,
.footer__navigation a:focus {
  color: #fff
}

.footer__item {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 12px 6px
}

@media screen and (min-width:840px) {
  .footer__item {
    padding: 0 20px
  }
}

.footer__item__link {
  text-decoration: none
}

.footer--social {
  margin: 0 auto 20px;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center
}

@media screen and (min-width:840px) {
  .footer--social {
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
    -ms-flex-order: 1;
    order: 1
  }
}

.footer__social-link {
  padding: 0 8px
}

.footer__social-link .icon {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  fill: #7e7e7e
}

.footer__social-link .icon:hover,
.footer__social-link .icon:focus {
  fill: #ccc
}

.footer-background {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 0;
  opacity: 0
}

.page-bottom .footer-background {
  opacity: 1
}


/* End of footer css. */

.button-collapse {
  color: #26a69a;
}

.parallax-container {
  min-height: 380px;
  line-height: 0;
  height: auto;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .9);
  overflow: visible;
}

.parallax-container .section {
  width: 100%;
}

.icon-block {
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.icon-block .material-icons {
  font-size: inherit;
}

footer.page-footer {
  margin: 0;
}

.materialboxed {
  width: 30%;
  margin: auto;
  float: left;
}

.brand-logo {
  width: 10%;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.carousel {
  overflow: visible;
}

.carousel .carousel-item {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.modal-body {
  color: black;
}

.loginbtn {
  background-color: #062605;
}

.btn {
  background-color: #032504;
}

.btn:hover,
.btn-large:hover {
  background-color: #1B5E20;
}

.btn:focus,
.btn-large:focus,
.btn-floating:focus {
  background-color: rgb(7, 31, 8);
}


/* CSS for modal. */

#login_register_btn {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

#login_lost_btn {
  float: left;
}

#login-btn {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

#register_login_btn {
  float: left;
}

#register-btn {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  padding: 0;
  /* max-height: 70%; */
  max-height: 59%;
  width: 55%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden !important;
  border-radius: 2px;
  will-change: top, opacity;
}

.modal-overlay {
  z-index: 0;
}

.modal .modal-content {
  padding: 24px;
  margin-bottom: 69px;
}


/* End CSS for Modal. */

@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .parallax-container .section {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
  }
  #index-banner .section {
    top: 10%;
  }
  /* This css is for the .main class */
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #index-banner .section {
    top: 0;
  }
}
```